# C++ casting to an object class using inherited parent class

Tags: c++

I have this class structure where classD and classE grandparents are the same

```
classB : classA;
classC : classA;

classD : classB;
classE : classC;
```

then I have a function which requires to pass an object classF

```
classF : classA;
function(classF *func);
```

Is it possible to pass an object of type classD and classE to function which requires type classF?
sample implementation as below:
Is it possible to just cast both to their common grandparent?

```
classD *d = new classD();
classE *e = new classE();

classA *func = (classA*)d;
function(func);

func = (classA*)e;
function(func);
```

Comment: Show real code please. For casting you should use `static_cast` in this case.

Comment: If `classF` is required, you need to serve `classF`. If `classA` provides everything that is needed inside `function(...)`, then change the parameter type accordingly.

Comment: it depends on what function does. It could call specific methods of classF.

Comment: If you want to cast `classB*` to `classF*` and use the result for anything, you are basically asking for undefined behavior.

Comment: Why not go with function(classA* func) instead? If you want it to process objects that are of classA or subclasses, then you write it to do so. If you don't want it, you don't give it objects of another type. That is basic OO. But actually I suspect that we got an XY-problem ( http://xyproblem.info/ ) here. What do you actually want to accomplish? Give us some names for your classes and the function. Whatever solution you need will have to be based on the idea and concept behind your classes. The answers talk about casting, which is of course correct, but we don't want (apple*) orange*.

Answer (score 3):

No, no and another time no.

The line that simply doesn't pass muster is this:

```
function(func);
```

This requires a downcast, i.e. - a cast from a parent class to its subclass. A downcast will not happen implicitly, which means the line will not compile (but had you provided compiling code, you would already know that). The following would compile:

```
function((classF*)func);
```

but you shouldn't use it. A downcast's result is undefined unless that reference originally belonged to that type. So, this is okay:

```
classF *f = new classF();
func = (classA*) f;
function((classF*)func);
```

But this is not:

```
classB *b = new classB();
func = (classA*) b;
function((classF*)func);
```

**Edited to add**

If the downcast is performed using the dedicated C++ cast operator `dynamic_cast`, then the code, at run time, makes sure that the down cast is correct. So:

```
classF *f = new classF();
func = (classA*) f;
classF *newf = dynamic_cast<classF *>(func); // Okay
classB *b = new classB();
func = (classA*) b;
newf = dynamic_cast<classF *>(func); // newf is now NULL
```

This allows run time checking that you have not made a mistake.

Personally, I like never relying on this for actual design, only for verification. In such a case, it is better to dynamic cast references rather than pointer. Dynamic casting an incorrect pointer results in NULL. Dynamic casting an incorrect reference throws an exception:

```
classF *f = new classF();
func = (classA*) f;
classF *newf = &dynamic_cast<classF &>(*func); // Okay
classB *b = new classB();
func = (classA*) b;
newf = &dynamic_cast<classF &>(*func); // Throws an exception
```

Answer (score 2):

If you function want a `classF` pointer you should pass it a `classF` pointer. Your code should not even compile like this because of the function requiring a `classF` and you give it a `classA`

You can get this to compile with casting the class to `classF` but **you should not do this**. This will get you into undefined behavior land because you would basically be lying to your compiler and say "*this other class is a `classF` pointer*", which would not be true.

What you can always safely do it cast to a pointer of the base class (like you do in your example with casting to `classA`)

You should also switch from c-style casts to c++ style casts (like `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`). This can also help you in your situation. With dynamic cast you can safely cast a class to a derrived class.

Like this:

```
class A {};

class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};

A* b-obj = new B;
A* c-obj = new C;
```

now both `c-obj` and `b-obj`are pointers to `A` so we don't know anymore if they are B or C. You can check this with `dynamic_cast`

```
C* ptr = dynamic_cast<C*>(b-obj); //returns null because b-obj cannot be converted to C*

C* ptr = dynamic_cast<C*>(c-obj); //does not return null
```

Your code can look like that then:

```
func = static_cast<A*>(e); // cast to base class.
//later then.
classF* funcF = dynamic_cast<F*>(func);
if(funcF != NULL)
{
    function(func);
}
```

the c-style casts can have some side effects you may not like. So **strongly** recommend to familiarize yourself with c++ casts.